# Script can't save data to file

Tags: python, blender

Based on *.blend file I have to write a script that gets informations about objects and saves them to json. This script can be opened in Blender, or running. The launch should save the json file with the data in the current directory.

So I created this:

```py
   import bpy
   import json

   objects = bpy.context.scene.objects
   data = {}

   for ob in objects:
       item = {}
       item['location'] = ob.location
       if ob.name == 'Cube':
           item['material_name'] = ob.active_material.name
           data[ob.name] = item
       elif ob.name == 'Camera':
           item['camera_type'] = ob.data.type
           data[ob.name] = item
       elif ob.name == 'Lamp':
           item['lamp_type'] = ob.data.type
           data[ob.name] = item

   with open('scene_objects.json', 'w') as json_file:
       json.dump(data, json_file)
```

However, when I run the script in Blender, I received the following error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'scene_objects.json'
```

I'm a beginner in using Blender so maybe it's impossible to write to file from Blender? However, if I can do it, I am asking for advice on how?

Comment: *"something like"*? Is this your actual code?

Comment: @NickA yes it's my actual code. I wrote a little confusingly.

Comment: I don't know Blender, but maybe there are places on the filesystem that you can write and places you can't, and writing to the current directory is one of the places you can't write to.  I'd suggest exploring if there are specific places on the filesystem that you can write to, like maybe "/tmp".

Comment: @Steve No it's not because of location. I tried to save it to different directories but still unsuccessful. Something musb be wrong with the way I try to save it. I thing the easiest solution will be using different method.

Comment: Make sure the user that is running the Blender process has permission to write into the directory where you want to store the json file.

Comment: "Something musb be wrong with the way I try to save it.".  That's pretty much not possible, or I at least have no idea what you're talking about.  You can either write to a particular file or you can't.  There's no "how" involved here.  If you weren't getting the right content in the file, that would be another thing.  But opening a file for writing is opening a file for writing. You can't do it "wrong". - I have no concept of what "other method" would make anything better.  There ARE other methods, but from my experience, they should all exhibit the same problem.

Comment: If Blender is something you run yourself, then @Ash is on the right track.  Your code does not have the rights to write where you're trying to write.  You have to either change where it is trying to write to somewhere it's allowed to write, or change the environment your code is running in such that you have permission to write to where you're trying to write.  Neither of these involves your Python code beyond changing the write location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue isn't with blender, the OS is preventing the creation (or writability) of the file based on file system permissions.

The line -

```
with open('scene_objects.json', 'w') as json_file:
```

will create a new file (or open existing) in the current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). When running blender that could be one of several options, depending on which OS you are using. It is also possible that starting blender from a GUI can leave you without a valid CWD, or a temporary dir that a user does not have permission to write to.

You can use [`os.chdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) to change the CWD to one that you know exists and that you can write to. You can also specify a full path instead of just a filename.